# Application's Document folder in iphone

Tags: iphone, dropbox

I am using dropbox API and downloading file in application document folder.

I am able to view list of files in table from document directory. How can I read photos or file from this table view?

And what about the iPhone. Can we access document folder directly?

Comment: application document folder is a part of SandBox. so you can not directly drop any item in to it . you can first add file to xCode proj(NSbundle). then only  can be access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the more commonly used approach to get the documents directory –

```
NSArray *searchResults = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [searchResults objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
```

You can use [`NSFileManager`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to examine the contents of the directory. You can look at the `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` method.

Comment: ok.Means I cant access document directory without code in iphone

Comment: No. Its possible. Look at [this](http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2010/11/file-sharing-from-app-to-itunes-is-too.html).

Comment: ok..and If I want to upload photos to dropbox.I should use imagepicker or can  I save images from camera to document folder?

Comment: Use `UIImagePicker` and handle the saving part in `imagePicker:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`.

Comment: You will have to save it. Better explained [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/camera/camera-application-to-take-pictures-and-save-images-to-photo-album.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply.Can you help me with audio recording.

Comment: lunch time..will be back in 1 hr

Answer (score 0):

Access document Folder -

```
NSDictionary *theCatalogInfo=nil;
NSString *theCatalogFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/",NSHomeDirectory()];
theCatalogFilePath = [theCatalogFilePath stringByAppendingString:@"File Name"];
if(nil!=theCatalogFilePath)
{


    theCatalogInfo=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:theCatalogFilePath];

}

return theCatalogInfo;
```