# How to get the file name in iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, memory

I stored a pdf file using NSData in my application memory. Now i want that file name each time to add those names into an array. How can i get the pdf file's name from my application memory to use in my app.

Comment: Application memory or application's Documents folder (disk) ? Would be pretty bad to just have a big NSData file just ocuppying RAM, plus it gets lost when the app is restarted.

Comment: Its in application documents folder.

Comment: This might help you out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093389/applications-document-folder-in-iphone

Answer (score 2):

You can't since you only stored the file as a data object and not it's file name.

You could try to read the PDF meta data to check if there's a file name.

Comment: My pdf file is stored in application documents folder.

Comment: Is this for the file stored in application memory's documents folder?

Comment: If your file is stored in the documents direct that you know the filename, because you saved it there. So when you load it in the NSData object you us the path and file. You will need to save the filename, in an array, as wel not just the data object.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here should help:

[Getting a list of files in the Resources folder - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398937/getting-a-list-of-files-in-the-resources-folder-ios)

It will list all the files in the Documents dir.

Comment: Or this, for other file manipulations: http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/file-saving-and-loading/using-the-document-directory-to-store-files

Comment: Is this for the file stored in application memory's documents folder?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in your last question. Can you rephrase?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose by "Application Memory" you mean one of the App's directories like Documents or Library.

You can just use **NSFileManager** to access the directory and get a list of all files, like if you stored it in your app's library folder:

```
NSArray* directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUSerDomainMask, YES];
NSString* path = [directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray* files = [NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path];
```

On top of that you can use a filter predicate to only get files with a .pdf ending.

Comment: For the documents dir the constant is NSDocumentDirectory.